# Angular 4 - pushing a new item to an array from an observable

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, observable

I have a page where I display a list with `locations`, and clicking on each of them I am displaying `assets` for that `location`. I have set up the template like this:

```
<li
    *ngFor="let location of locations"
    (click)="select(location)"
    droppable
    [dragOverClass]="'drag-target-border'"
    (onDrop)="onItemDrop($event, location)"
    >
      {{ location.name }}
      <ul *ngIf="currentLocation == location && assetsVisible">
        <ng-container *ngIf="currentLocation.assets?.length > 0;else message">
          <li
            *ngFor="let asset of currentLocation.assets"
            class="asset"
            draggable
            [dragData]="asset"
            >
            <p>{{ asset.title }}</p>
            <p>{{ asset.address }}</p>
            <p>{{ asset.value }}</p>
          </li>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-template #message>No assets for {{ location.name }}</ng-template>
      </ul>
  </li>
```

And in the component, I have set the empty `assets` array, and an empty `currentLocation`:

```
  locations: any[] = [];
  currentLocation: any = {};
  assets: any[] = [];
```

And then in the method `select` I am fetching the assets like this:

```
  select(location:any = {){

    if (this.currentLocation != location || !this.assetsVisible) {
      this.assetsVisible = true;
    }
    else {
      this.assetsVisible = false;
    }

    this.currentAddress = address;

    this.locationService.getAssets(location.Id)
      .subscribe(
        assets => this.assets = assets
      );
  }
```

What I would like to do is to since I am using [the drag and drop plugin for Angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-drag-drop#droppable-directive) I would like to make it possible for user to drag assets from one location to another. And then just temporarily push that asset to an array `assets`.
I have made a function for that:

```
onItemDrop(e: any, location:any = {}) {
   this.assets = [];
   this.assets.push(e.dragData);        
   this.select(location);
}
```

So, when a user drags and drops the asset from one location to another, I am emptying the `assets` array, and pushing the new asset that was dragged to the array.
But, then in the `select` method I am getting all the `assets` for that new `location` that the `asset` was dropped to, and that rewrites the `assets` array. 
How can I push to the same array those `assets`, so that I have both the new `asset` added and the `assets` of that `location` that I get from the service endpoint?
I have tried another approach as well, where I was first emptying array assets, and then calling and passing new `location` and new `asset` to `select` method:

```
onItemDrop(e: any, location:any = {}) {
    this.assets = [];
    this.select(location, e.dragData);
  }
```

And then, in the `select` method I have set the `asset` parameter as optional, and then pushing it there to the `assets` array after I got all the `assets` for that `location` from the service:

```
select(location:any = {}, asset?:any = {}) {


    this.locationService.getAssets(location.Id)
      .subscribe(
        assets => this.assets = assets,
        if (asset) {this.assets.push(asset)} 
      );
  }
```

But, that didn't work, the asset dropped to new location wasn't displayed in the template. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well in your first approach, you're overwriting your `assets` array in your `subscribe` function:

```
this.locationService.getAssets(location.Id).subscribe(
    assets => this.assets = assets
);
```

So obviously, the `asset` you temporarily saved in that array is lost at this point.

Your second approach makes more sense, but you're using `subscribe` wrong in this example:

```
this.locationService.getAssets(location.Id).subscribe(
    assets => this.assets = assets,
    if (asset) {this.assets.push(asset)} 
);
```

In this case the `if (asset) ...` part is passed as the second argument to your `subscribe` call which is the `error callback`. You want to do it like this:

```
this.locationService.getAssets(location.Id).subscribe( (assets) => {
    this.assets = assets;
    if (asset) {
         this.assets.push(asset)
    } 
});
```

Hope it helps.

Update: 
I'm not even sure if that `if (asset) ...` part, the way you implemented it, is even working as error callback. you probably get an error there if that callback is called because a function is expected, not an expression (but as i said, i'm not sure about that).

Comment: That was the mistake, thank you very much for your help!